# Is it bad practice to nest states in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been working on a project and have gotten help from a couple of people. One of them told me it would be a better idea to nest my states, and so I did. However, when I got help from someone else they had told me that nesting states is not a good idea and that I should avoid doing it. I don't have a lot of experience with this at all but I would like to do it the better/most practical way possible. Does anyone have any input?

Here's an example of what I meant by nested states:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        someGroup = [{
            somePartA: "",
            somePartB: [],
            someKey: uuid()
        }],
        somethingElse = "",
        anotherOne = "",
    }
}
```

And here's what I mean by not nested

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        somePartA: "",
        somePartB: [],
        someKey: uuid(),
        somethingElse = "",
        anotherOne = "",
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: None of the approaches are necessarily wrong, but the more nested your state is, the tougher it will be to update a part of your state with `setState`.

Comment: I see, are there any other downsides of nested states?

Comment: Not really. It's more error prone and harder to work with if you have state that is too nested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally a good idea to keep your state shallow.

If you have a complex application, it's an even better idea to limit state to UI concerns and use a state container outside of the component like Redux, especially when the data you're keeping in state is more application data than local component concerns.

This is potentially a big topic with loads of opinion. If you haven't yet I would read up on React state design. Here are some articles. Keep in mind there's no single answer. But these should help you build a foundation.

- [Thinking In React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)
- [State Shape](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/optimising-the-state-shape-of-your-react-app-with-redux-3a280e6ef436)
- [Why Use Redux?](https://hackernoon.com/why-redux-cbfc6fc5f788)

Comment: I noticed in the "Thinking in React" article they kind of, I think, avoided having to nest functions by separating the pieces of their app into different classes (correct me if I'm wrong), would you recommend this over having everything in one class? Or is this more of just a preference thing?

Comment: Yes, modular components are awesome! Even in a relatively simple application. Separation of concerns but tight coupling for component-level features.